# Braucht dieser Satz "mit ihnen" oder ist "damit die Menschen" genug?

Tags: standard-german

> Konsequent brauchen wir einen Platz, *damit die Menschen*, *mit ihnen* wir jeden Tag um uns herum begegnen, besser und mehr kennenlernen.

Braucht dieser Satz „mit ihnen“ oder ist „damit die Menschen“ genug?

Answer (score 4):

Ich würde vorschlagen, den Satz so zu schreiben:
"**K**onsequent**erweise** brauchen wir einen **P**latz, um die Menschen, **denen** wir jeden Tag begegnen, besser kennenzulernen."
Mit etwas mehr Kontext, könnte man die Antwort wohl noch verbessern.